# Trigger event on back button header in meteor with ionic framework

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework

I am using meteor ionic package to build application. This is my template code.

```
<template name="offerDetails">
    {{#contentFor "headerButtonLeft"}}
        {{>ionNavBackButton path="home"}}
    {{/contentFor}}

    {{#ionView}}
            {{#ionContent}}
              //SOME OTHER HTMLS CODES

            {{/ionContent}}
    {{/ionView}}
    {{#if isNext}}
        {{#ionFooterBar class="bar-blurred next"}}
            <div class="pull-right">
                Ok, Next
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
        {{/ionFooterBar}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

How can I trigger a template event when in the header that is in the back button. I know it does not fall inside template. But what is the best fix

Comment: waiting for an answer too.